# flume-ng --conf /conf agent -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have installed `Flume 1.6.0-cdh5.4.2` in `CentOS` (`cloudera VM`)

I think configuration and all everything is ok

I ran the following command flume

```
flume-ng --conf /conf  agent -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

but i am not getting any error and any output. why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `/bin/flume-ng` file and add a `set -x` at the top so you will see the debug output for the bash file. Maybe that helps